# How to get a Cursor from a case-insensitive string (ex. from "hand" instead of "Hand")?

Tags: c#, wpf, string-comparison, typeconverter

I have the string representation of a particular type of mouse cursor, in several different cases such as: "Hand", "hand", "haNd", etc.

How do I get the correct `Cursor` while ignoring the case of the string?

The `TypeConverter.ConvertFromString` method does not support a `StringComparison` parameter.

```
var cursor = CursorConverter().ConvertFromString("hand"); // not "Hand"
```

Comment: Why not convert input string to the right form by making the first character upper case and the rest lower?

Comment: Because of `Cursors.ScrollAll`, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the `Cursor` property you want, while ignoring letter case:

```
var cursor = (Cursor)typeof(Cursors).GetProperty("haNd",
    BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);
```

Checking out the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.cursorconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I don't see anything in the `CursorConverter` class that would allow you to ignore case.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.cursorconverter(v=vs.110).aspx